# Does the magnitude of centripetal acceleration always stay the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I'm in ap physics 1 and currently learning uniform circular motion. Does the magnitude of centripetal acceleration always stay the same even in a vertical circular motion?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you think it should depend on wheter the motion is vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

If the speed of the motion is constant, then yes, the centripetal acceleration is constant. Otherwise, the centripetal acceleration changes according to
$$a_c = \frac{v^2}{r}$$
where $a_c$ is the centripetal acceleration, $v$ is the current speed, and $r$ is the radius of the circular motion.

However, in vertical circular motion where the only forces are gravity and rope tension (like a ball on a rope), then keeping a constant speed is impossible. At the point where the rope is horizontal and the ball's motion is vertical, there is no force to counteract gravity, so the ball will be speeding up or slowing down.

Answer (score 0):

### Does $a_c$ stay constant

Short answer: It depends.

The centripetal acceleration is given by
$$a_c=\dfrac{v^2}{r}.$$

For an object to be in circular motion, the radius $r$ will be constant -- that is obvious. Therefore, for $a_c$ to not remain constant, $v$ must not remain constant. i.e. the object is either speeding up or slowing down.

Therefore, $a_c$ will also be constant if and only if the speed $v$ is also constant. This is referred to as **Uniform Circular Motion**.

When the speed changes (that is, $v$ changes and so there is tangential acceleration i.e. speeding up/slowing down), then $a_c$ must also change. This is obvious by looking at the formula above. When the speed changes, then centripetal acceleration cannot be constant. This is known as **Non-uniform Circular Motion**.

### Does $a_c$ stay constant in vertical motion

Again, it depends.

***Scenario 1.*** Consider (as stated by @Mark H), a ball on a rope undergoing vertical circular motion. Since the only force that affects the speed of the ball is gravity, then as the ball goes up, it gains gravitational potential energy and thus slows down. (why does *tension* not affect the *speed*? because tension in this case is always perpendicular to the velocity. you will learn that if a force is perpendicular to the velocity, that force will not change the speed, only the direction of velocity). Anyway, moral of the story is: the $a_c$ a ball attached to a string spinning around in a vertical circle will not be constant, because the speed $v$ changes.

***Scenario 2.*** Ferris wheel. A person sitting in a Ferris wheel can go around at constant speed (due to the normal forces external on the person by the Ferris). In this case, $a_c$ will be constant.

For your course, you must be able to identify when the speed is and isn't constant, which will tell you whether or not $a_c$ is constant.

Hope this long answer helps.